# Error messages (multiple defined symbols) after including a class file

Tags: c++, class

I am using the g++ compiler on a linux mint.
I´m tying to make a class for neural Network witch i want play tic tac toe.
My Header:

```
#ifndef tttAi
#define tttAi
#include <string>

class Synaps{
public:
    explicit Synaps(const std::string& n, double v);
    void add(double ad);
    void multi(double mu);
    void save();
    double read();
private:
    std::string name;
    double Syn_value;
};
#endif
```

My functions are:

```
    #include "tttAi.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

Synaps::Synaps(const std::string& n, double v)
:name(n), Syn_value(v){
}

void Synaps::add(double ad) { //change by addition
    Syn_value += ad;
}

void Synaps::multi(double multip) { //change by multiplication
    Syn_value *= multip;
}

double Synaps::read() {
    return Syn_value;
}
```

And here is what i wanted it to do:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "tttAi.h"
#include "tttAi.cpp"

int main() {
Synaps n1n6("n1n6", 75);
n1n6.multi(2);

std::cout << n1n6.read() << '\n';
/*Want it to just output the value of Syn_value Witch at
this point should be 150 if i have done everything right*/
}
```

Command used: g++ -Wall -std=c++14 *cpp

so what i would think i´d get was just the consol output of 150 but whilst compiling i get this endless error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05VIq.jpg)

hope you have a idea of what i did wrong, any ideas welcome.

Comment: Please copy and paste the error message here rather than posting a screen shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including a cpp file containing definitions multiple times (i.e. you should not write

```
#include "tttAi.cpp"
```

in your main.cpp file) and therefore violating the [ODR - one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Remember that including a file means duplicating that file's contents in the point of inclusion (and therefore duplicating your definitions as well).

Comment: What does ODR mean? I think using an abbreviation without an explanation is more confusing than helpful for a newbie to C++.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall right, sorry for the double rule-ing. Added more context altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be #include "tttAi.cpp" in your main.cpp file.
You should not include cpp files

Answer (score 0):

You should not `#include` .cpp files. Instead, just list them on the command line when you compile.